# Correctly localize variables in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I’m doing a little project for Wolfram Demonstration. When I create snapshots, i.e. paste several times Output cell of Manipulate, all of them updates simultaneously, if any control is changed.
I understand it’s about localizing variables, trying to apply `Module` inside and outside - nothing helps.

This demo-code repeats the key features of my project. It is undesirable to abandon `Dynamic` or `TrackingFunction`. It is also important that `pts` are updated completely only after `num` change, not `steps`.

I’m sure the problem is in `pts` variable, but I don’t know how to localize it while retaining the core features of the project.

```
Clear[mainStep]; Manipulate[
 pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, 2}];
 mainStep[data_] := If[Length@data > 1, Rest@data, data];
 Dynamic[Graphics[Point@pts, ImageSize -> 100]],

 {{num, 10}, 5, 20, 1, ContinuousAction -> False},

 {steps, 1, 10, 1,
  TrackingFunction -> (steps = #; pts = mainStep[pts]; &)
  },
 TrackedSymbols :> {num}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule of thumb: if you're localizing something related to dynamics, use `DynamicModule`:

```
DynamicModule[{pts},
 Manipulate[pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, 2}];
  Dynamic[Graphics[Point@pts, ImageSize -> 100]], {{num, 10}, 5, 20, 1, 
   ContinuousAction -> False}, {steps, 1, 10, 1, 
   TrackingFunction -> (steps = #; pts = mainStep[pts]; &)}, 
  Initialization :> (Clear[mainStep]; 
    mainStep[data_] := If[Length@data > 1, Rest@data, data];), 
  TrackedSymbols :> {num}]]
```

I've also moved the definition of `mainStep` to `Initialization` option, this isn't necessary, but a little better because then the definition of `mainStep` will be evaluated only once.

Comment: Yes, many thanks, now each snap works separately!
The only point - the rules of Wolfram Demonstrations require that the outer wrapper always was Manipulate. But since everything works, I hope there will be no problems

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option. This uses the second argument of dynamics. No need to make separate function `mainStep` as you can do this directly in the second argument slot.

With this method, you just need to initialize the variables `num` and `steps` and `pts` to initial values using the `None` type for Dynamics, which was introduced I think in version 7 or 9 of Mathematica.

See if this does what you want.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Graphics[Point@pts, ImageSize -> {200, 200}],
 Grid[{{"steps", Manipulator[Dynamic[steps, {steps =#; pts = If[Length@pts > 1, Rest@pts, pts]} &], {5, 20, 1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic@steps},
   {"num", Manipulator[Dynamic[num, {num = #; pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {num, 2}]} &], {5, 20, 1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny, ContinuousAction -> False], Dynamic@num}
   }],

 (*initialize all Manipulate variables once*)
 {{steps, 5}, None},
 {{num, 10}, None},
 {{pts, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {num}
 ]
```